# Im having trouble populating ListTile in ListView.builder from database

Tags: android, listview, flutter

Im having trouble populating ListTile in ListView.builder from database.
I dont have "model class" since i dont need to update delete data i just need simple query.

I have ExpansionTile with three categories and in each one i need query from db. I dont know hoe to write or what to return from db class for this to work.

```
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, i) => ExpansionTile(
                      title: new Text(
                        '${categoryName[i]}',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(49, 85, 158, 1)),
                      ),
                      children: list                //final list = new List.generate(17, (i) => "Item ${i + 1}"); --just to populete with dummy items, instad of this i need db data
                          .map((val) => ListTile(
                                  // leading: Icon(Icons.add),
                                  title: new Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  new Checkbox(
                                      value: _isCheck,
                                      onChanged: (bool value) {
                                        onChange(value);

                                      }),
                                  new Expanded(child: new Text(val)),
                                ],
                              )))
                          .toList(),
                    ),
                itemCount: categoryName.length,
              ),
            ),


          ],
        ),
```

From my db class :

```
  Future<List> getAllNotes() async {
    var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(databasesPath, 'books.db');
    Database database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1);
    //var dbClient = await database();
    var result = await database.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $booksTable WHERE $colDescription = ${'Adventure'}');


    return result.toList();
  }
```

So how to write simple query to get result in ListView/ListTile?

Answer (score 0):

You really need to provide much more details about your problem. Anyways, ill try to answer with what I have understood.

Let's say you have a table names 'booksTable' with 3 fields:

```
bookId | bookName | bookCategory
  1       Book A     Adventure
  2       Book B      History
  3       Book C     Adventure
  4       Book D      History
```

Make sure you create all these database functions in `DatabaseHelper()` class, so that you don't have to write logic to db again and again.

Now you query will look something like this:

```
Future<List<String>> getAllNotes(String category) async {
    var dbClient = await database();
 List<String> bookNames = List<String();
    var result = await dbClient.rawQuery("SELECT bookname FROM booksTable WHERE bookCategory = $category");
result.forEach((item) {
 bookNames.add(item["bookname"]);
});
    return bookNames;
      }
```

This will work only if you have to deserialise 1 column. If you have multiple columns selected, you have to create a model class.

Now in your front view, you have two options:
1) You can use initState to populate your List with bookNames of category in the parameter
2) You can use FutureBuilder to populate your list as well
(You have to use StatefulWidget for both these options)

I'll show you how to do it using initState here. If you want to know how to do it using FutureBuilder, let me know in comments.

```
List<String> booksList =List<String>();
var db = DatabaseHelper();

readList() async {
booksList = await db.getAllNotes("Adventure");
}

@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
 readList();
}

ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
Column( crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, 
          children: <Widget>[
               ExpansionTile(
                      title: new Text(
                        "Adventure Category",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(49, 85, 158, 1)),
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                                  title: new Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  new Checkbox(
                                      value: _isCheck,
                                      onChanged: (bool value) {
                                        onChange(value);
                                      }),
                                  Expanded(child: new Text("${booksList[i]}")),
                                ],
                              )))
                    ),])}
                itemCount: booksList.length,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
```

**Note:** There might be typos in the code above, since i have typed it on phone, but you get the idea how to do it, right?

Comment: `bookNames.add(item['Category']);` Instead of "Category", you'll have to write `$colDescription` i.e. `bookNames.add(item['$colDescription'])`. You have to map the your list items, so you write the column name to map it. Rest seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

So, i have ListView (with 3 expanded groups) im geting them from array: ( List categoryName = ['Part 1: Adventure', 'Part 2:  History','Part 3: Horror'];
And passing then here :
     child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, i) => ExpansionTile(
                      title: new Text(
                        '${categoryName[i]}',
                      ),

That part working fine, i get 3 expandeble titles, now children of that ( ListTile ) need to be populate from db .
With your example :

readList() async {
    sinsAgainstGod = await db.getSins("Adventure");

}
I get error: ...near "Adventure": syntax error..
And keep geting  0 lenght on booksList...

```
  Future<List<String>> getNotes(String category) async {
    var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(databasesPath, 'books.db');
    Database database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1);

    List<String> bookNames = List<String>();
    var result = await database.rawQuery("SELECT $colDescription FROM $booksTable WHERE = $category ");
    result.forEach((item) {
      bookNames.add(item['Category']);

    });
    return bookNames;
  }
```

What this result.forEach(item) suppose to do?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer it was helpful.
Can you tell me why im getting 20 same description instead literate through all with this code:

```
  Future<List<String>> getSins(String column) async {
    var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(databasesPath, 'confession.db');
    Database database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1);

    List<String> bookNames = List<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      var result = await database.rawQuery(
          'SELECT * FROM $plannerTable WHERE $colCategory= "Adventure');
      bookNames.add((result[0][column].toString()));
    }

    return bookNames;
}
```

I want to get all decription from adventure category. Tnx